# Does one get a Facebook notification when someone edited their comment to your post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I've seen differing reports on this question and would like to get to the bottom of it. While some say (including myself, having tested it with my two Facebook accounts) that no notifications are sent out after someone **edited** their *existing* comment, there are those who **have received** one

(https://www.quora.com/Does-editing-a-comment-on-Facebook-send-out-a-notification/answer/Elling-Lien, https://www.quora.com/Does-editing-a-comment-on-Facebook-send-out-a-notification/answer/Elling-Lien/comment/14026784).

One person claims it only happens if the original comment was posted while the post's author was offline.

What are your experiences? How can this Facebook behavior be officially ascertained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook sends a notification only in certain situations. One situation is described as follows

Say a user comments on a friend's post.

[image: User A posts comments on User B post]

That friend now replies

[image: User B comments]

Now the condition here is that the friend is offline for an unspecified amount of time when the initial user changed his comment.

[image: Edited comment]

At this point when the friend logs in again there should be a notification stating a post was edited.

[image: Edit notification]

Apart from this scenario (and any others yet to be found) there is no official way (until a Facebook help section about it appears) to validate the precise conditions a notification does appear when a post is edited.

Comment: Great, phwd. Thanks! Can you confirm that a notification is NOT sent out when I leave a comment to my own post directly after the person's comment (so it appears beneath it), go offline and in the meantime the person edits her/his comment?

Comment: @Aquinax yes that falls in line with the scenario above (I tested it)